# Hovering parent element triggers multiple elements including itself

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```css
h3,
h2 {
  color: green;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

h2:hover,
h3:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav justify-content-between">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h3>Sibling</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h2>Parent</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h3>Sibling</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to have the parent heading trigger a color change on hover on itself and the the sibling headings, but, when the sibling heading is hovered over, it doesn't trigger any elements? I used bootstrap to style the list etc.
Also is it possible to do this using css only?

**Working JSFIDDLE Link:** https://jsfiddle.net/jd9nenwa/6/

Comment: the element you call sibling are not sibling .. they don't belong to the same parent

Comment: This is not working at all, because the <h>-elements are not neigbours... They must have the same parent!

Comment: Yeah I should've named it something else. I know that the h2 tag isnt a parent .

Comment: But even then you would be just able to change <h3>-elements which come after you <h2> and not the one before!

Comment: It is not possible just with css, you will need to take JS!

Comment: Well, can you give me a solution please?

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript you could also change your HTML to use div containers to wrap around the groups you want to change color on. Not sure if that's an option for you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code out. I had to change the hierarchy a bit.

```css
h3,
h2 {
  color: green;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

h2:hover~.heading, h2:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <h2 class="heading">Parent</h2>
  <h3 class="heading">Sibling</h3>
  <h3 class="heading">Sibling</h3>
```

Comment: This works in this particular case but this  code will color all other h3 following, even if there are other h2 in between, so this wont work for a whole menu, or you must seperate parent and sibling belonging to them from others...

Comment: You can use different classes instead of h2.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not possible with pure CSS. There is a [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), but that only matches siblings that come after your selector, not before it.

You would need to use JQuery/JavaScript at the moment to achieve what you want:

```
    $('h2').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover').closest('.nav').find('h3').addClass('hover');
    });
    $('h2').on('mouseleave', function() {  

  $(this).removeClass('hover').closest('.nav').find('h3').removeClass('hover');    });
```

Also requires the CSS to be updated to include a .hover class:

```
h2:hover, h2.hover,
h3:hover, h3.hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I added that to the jsfiddle and it isn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/jd9nenwa/24/

Comment: Here you go, I was missing a . on my .nav and it needed JQuery and the hover classes including: https://jsfiddle.net/78Lw857a/ - I have updated the answer, let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a solution with js, just with css it is sadly not possible, as explained in comments above...

```js
$("h2").mouseenter(function() {
  $("h3").css("color","red");
});

$("h2").mouseleave(function() {
  $("h3").css("color","green");
});
```

```css
h3,
h2 {
  color: green;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

h2:hover,
h3:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav justify-content-between">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h3>Sibling</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h2>Parent</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h3>Sibling</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer is more practical and it worked flawlessly in my project. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated according to comments, `h2` hover triggers color change for all headers, `h3` hover triggers hover for only `h3`.

```
$('.nav-item h2').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.heading').css('color','red');
  });
$('.nav-item h2').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.heading').css('color','green')
  });
$('.nav-item h3').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.nav-item h3').css('color','red');
  });
$('.nav-item h3').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.nav-item h3').css('color','green')
  });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jd9nenwa/29/

Comment: When you hover over the H2, the h3 will also get triggered aswell. However, when you hover the h3 the h2 doesnt get triggered. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         
        $(".a").hover(function () {
            $(".a").css("color", "red");
        }, function () {
            $(".b").css("color", "black");
            });

        $(".b").hover(function () {
            $(".a").css("color", "yellow");
        }, function () {
            $(".b").css("color", "pink");
            });
        
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav justify-content-between">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <p class="a">Sibling</p>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <p class="b">Parent</p>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <p class="a">Sibling</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```